# Should I let the user create a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on a school register system (it's my first PHP project) and I want it to be available not just for one school. I guess that each school should have its own database. So what I did is that after the user signs up a new school and clicks a "Create a new school register" button, a new database is created with empty tables for teachers, students, attendance etc.

At the same time I have a whole other database with just one table to store all the different schools that are going to sign up. I need it for checking if email already exists and so on.

It works but I sense that this is not how it should be done. Or is it? The app uses one hard-coded database name and then other database names are created by the user. (I've made it so the dynamically created db names have a 'school_' prefix and whatever the user names the school is then appended to it. White spaces are replaced by undescores.)

Do I need to change my approach? Thanks!

Comment: Do you also maintain separate versions of the code for each school?

Comment: No I don't. I haven't thought about that. I want it to be available but I only have one school in mind that wants to use it

Answer (score 2):

There are pros and cons for both approaches and you have to evaluate what is more important to you and how you believe the project is going to evolve.

Pros for having separate databases:

- Easier to customize the installation for each school - imagine you get a school that has special requirements, and the easiest way to implement them involves adding columns to tables
- Easier to migrate a school to a separate installation of the app - imagine a school gets new management and insists on on-premises hosting after a year

Pros for having a single database:

- Easier to upgrade: if a new feature means you need to change the database schema, you only have to change one schema, not one per school
- Easier to produce global cross-school statistics: suppose you want a report that has information from different schools - with a single database you only need to run one query, with separate databases you need one query per database

You may also want to think about how you version the source code. If you'll maintain separate versions of the source code for each school so that you can have custom features per school, it makes sense to have separate databases. If you only want to maintain a single version, then it'll probably be easier to have a single database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what the requirements are, but I think the simpler approach would be to have a single database. When a new school is created, add an entry to the “schools” table. Have a foreign key “school_id” in each table that links to the “schools” table.

Comment: No, you just have one table named “students” and one named “teachers” etc. You can get all the students for a specific school with something like “select * from students where school_id = 3”